# Namespaces in SOAP services

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, namespaces

I am trying to write unit tests for my WSDL SOAP web service in Java.

Problem occurs, when I try to assert XML equality, of how response from web service should look like and what it actually looks like.

I have no idea why I get the following error:

```
Expected namespace prefix "pns111", but was "ns3"
```

So here, pns111 is my defined namespace for web service. Why do I receive ns3 namespace? And why specifically ns3? I have not defined ns3 namespace anywhere, is this namespace somehow special?

Also, I get another error regarding XML equality assertion:

```
Expected presence of child nodes to be 'true', but was 'false'.
```

Can you give me any clue of this error as well?

Answer (score 0):

In XML the prefix used for a namespace need not be the same for two XML documents to be considered equal. It helps to think of the namespace prefix as nothing more than an abbreviation for the namespace URI.

These two XML documents are the same from an XML processing standpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo:root xmlns:foo="http://example.com">
  <foo:node>Hi!</foo:node>
</foo:root>
```

And:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bar:root xmlns:bar="http://example.com">
  <bar:node>Hi!</bar:node>
</bar:root>
```

In the first example `foo` means “the http://example.com namespace”. In the second one `bar` too points to the same namespace.

So in your test you should be verifying that the **namespace URI** matches the expected one. Which prefix is used is not relevant, as long as it is consistent within the XML document.

It depends on the library generating your XML if it will use the prefix you specified or pick one itself.